# How to set a value asynchronously and fetch it at a later stage

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I wish to set the value of a variable asynchronously. Following that I want to get that value at a later stage. How can I do that? This is what I am doing currently to achieve this. Is this a proper implementation or should I have gone for CompletableFuture?

When a rest call is made, this is one of the first method that is called.

```
public class A{

    @Autowired
    private Helper helper;

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void stepOne(Model model) {

        MyObj myObj = model.myObj;
        // helper.decrypt() returns a String
        Future<String> futureNumber = executor.submit(() -> helper.decrypt());
        myObj.setFutureNumber(futureNumber);
    }
}

// coming to following method after awhile going to various other classes / methods 
// now I need the value myObj.getFutureNumber(). 

public class B{
    public void stepTwo(Model model) {

        // model should now have the value 100
        MyObj myObj = model.myObj;
        final String number = null;

        try{
            myObj.setNumber(myObj.getFutureNumber().get());
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(myObj.getNumber() == 100){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This is MyObj

```
public class MyObj{
    private String number;
    private Future<String> futureNumber;
    // get set methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, with `CompletableFuture` you can set number asynchronously much easier. Here is one possible way:

```
public CompletableFuture<Model> setNumberAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> helper.decrypt())
            .thenCombine(stepsBeforeSettingNumber(), (number, model) -> {
                MyObj myObj = model.myObj;
                myObj.setNumber(number);
                if (myObj.getNumber() == 100) {
                    // do something
                }
                return model;
            });
}

public CompletableFuture<Model> stepsBeforeSettingNumber() {
    //  going to various other classes / methods
```